# Is there a way to filter all content on page?

Tags: wordpress

I need to run a 'preg_replace' on all the content on the page including inside widget content, header footer and all other places displayed. How can i run through all output on page?

I am wanting to replace all bad words could possibly occur on a page. I just don't know how to search all content on the page.

Comment: Are you sure that's really what you *need* to do?

Answer (score 0):

Running a preg_replace on your whole content is extremely costly in terms of performance and I'm not sure about what to think of it, but there is a way to do it.

Best way would be to use the output buffer
 to get all your content into a variable, then fiddle with it all you want,
then output the final result.

It'll look like this:

```
// starts the output buffer
ob_start(); 

// In your case this is where all the content output is going to go. This echo is just a sample
echo "badword\n"; 

// get all the buffered content output
$OB = ob_get_contents(); 

// clean the buffered content, and also end the output buffer 
ob_end_clean(); 

// run a replace on all the buffered content, and echo it out
echo preg_replace("/badword/", "BEEP", $OB);
```